# How does the interpretation of consumption of flesh and blood differ in certain denominations?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, communion, comparative-christianity, transubstantiation

During a mass, there's the moment when the congregation express their connection to Jesus by consuming his (metaphorical) flesh and blood (in practice, wine and bread).

Today, we discussed that sacrament and a question popped up. Since Jesus is both a human (sent by God) and a god (as a part of the holy trinity, son of God), whose flesh and blood is consumed? Is it the human Jesus' or the godly Jesus'?

Or perhaps it's not known or impossible to make the distinction?

Furthermore, if such a distinction can be defined, what does that imply? Does the congregation express the connection to the earthly Jesus who dies? Or the resurrected Jesus who's about to ascend?

I learned form comments that it also will depend on the denomination, so I'm curious about the difference between Catholics, Orthodox and Protestants.

Comment: Are you asking about the Catholic view? They're the ones who call communion "mass", but they don't consider it to be metaphorical...

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  Since different denominations answer differently, I think you will need to add a scope to it by explicitly asking a denomination's point of view (Catholic, Reformed, Lutheran, Eastern Orthodox, etc.) and tag it accordingly (`catholicism`, `reformed-theology`, `lutheranism`, `eastern-orthodox`, etc.).  Or you can ask an [overview question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/10672).

Comment: Since you are saying it's metaphorical, can't it be both?

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't understand. If it's not metaphorical, that would be cannibalism and actual flesh/blood. But that's not what I mean at all. I mean in a very respectful and serious manner, of course.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather It could be, too. Correct. I was looking for the insights and interpretation from others, though. I already learned that it actually may differ depends on the denomination, which I wasn't even considering as a factor. Silly of me...